# Application is not running by using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here I'm working on login activity where it stores user's username and password using firebase and when I'm trying to run this Activity on my emulator its shows app has been stopped.I checked the code twice but couldn't found that error.I give Internet permission as well as Firebase Client,Authentication and Core library.Does it need any other libarary

```
package com.example.firebasedemo;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText user1,pass2;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseauth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAutoSateListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        user1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.toSignIN);
        mFirebaseauth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAutoSateListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser=mFirebaseauth.getCurrentUser();
                if (mFirebaseUser!=null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"You are logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please Login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username=user1.getText().toString();
                String password=pass2.getText().toString();
                if (username.isEmpty())
                {
                    user1.setError("Please enter email ID");
                    user1.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (password.isEmpty())
                {
                    pass2.setError("Please enter Password");
                    pass2.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (username.isEmpty()&& password.isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Fields are Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (!username.isEmpty()&& password.isEmpty())
                {
                   mFirebaseauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username,password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                           if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                               Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login error ,Please login Again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           }
                           else {
                               Intent i=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                               startActivity(i);
                           }
                       }
                   });
                            }
                            else {
                               Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                               startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i =new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
                }
                protected void onStart()
                {
                    super.onStart();
                    mFirebaseauth.addAuthStateListener(mAutoSateListener);
                }

            }
```

Comment: it would be help if you post your error from Logcat

Comment: Then, Chcek it in real device.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have some errors on the logic in this line here?

```
else if (!username.isEmpty()&& password.isEmpty())
```

I think it should be

```
else if (!username.isEmpty()&& !password.isEmpty())
```

Also, it would be helpful to show your error messages here.